# php regex to match pattern

Tags: php, regex

How could I extract the email part from all of the following strings cases:

```
"Robert Donhan" <bob@email.com>
Robert Donhan <bob@email.com>
"Robert Donhan" bob@email.com
Robert Donhan bob@email.com
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. The proper way to 'thank' someone on Stack Overflow is to up-vote the useful answers and accept the one that solved your problem in the end.

Comment: ...however, you need at least 15 reputation points to upvote. Accepting is always possible (click the checkmark on the left of the answer that helped you the most).

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with this regex:

```
([\\w-+]+(?:\\.[\\w-+]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})
```

Anyway, I suggested this site: [TXT2RE](http://www.txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=%22Robert%20Donhan%22%20%3Cbob@email.com%3E&3)

Comment: That site looks really awesome! Worth an upvote. I'm not sure how well it'd do in keeping in mind special characters that aren't in the default teststring, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely correct but the following regex mostly works:

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}
```

with case insensitive option

[**Rubular Link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/viG2FrLD2f)

Comment: That `{2,4}` should be `{2,6}` (Don't leave out `.MUSEUM` and `.TRAVEL`!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
/(^|\s)<?([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,6})>?(\n|\r|\s|$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your regex can be simpler. Split(explode) on the string using whitepace, go through each item, and check of "@". Then remove all `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not necessarily need a regular expression, you could use [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist) or [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses`](http://php.net/mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses) to get both the address and the name.